# RegEx for capturing part of a structured string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to extract a substring from the string.

```
top - 16:04:32 up 69 days, 2 min, 0 users, load average: 0.39, 0.39, 0.41|Tasks: 64 total, 1 running, 63 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie|%Cpu(s): 2.3 us, 11.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 86.3 id, 0.1 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.1 si, 0.0 st|KiB Mem: 511268 total, 171828 used, 339440 free, 71632 buffers|KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 used, 0 free. 67608 cached Mem|
```

From the above string: I want only:

```
|KiB Mem: 511268 total, 171828 used, 339440 free, 71632 buffers|
```

The pattern is the same, but the numbers might change.

`KiB\sMem\` is the regex I have been trying.

Comment: Do you want to capture the numbers ? Are there a lot of these substrings in there ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, we want to use a left and right boundary based on our string and desired outputs and collect the data that we like, maybe an expression similar to this:

```
(\|KiB.+?buffers\|)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5VX1pG/1)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(\|KiB.+?buffers\|)/gm;
const str = `top - 16:04:32 up 69 days, 2 min, 0 users, load average: 0.39, 0.39, 0.41|Tasks: 64 total, 1 running, 63 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie|%Cpu(s): 2.3 us, 11.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 86.3 id, 0.1 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.1 si, 0.0 st|KiB Mem: 511268 total, 171828 used, 339440 free, 71632 buffers|KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 used, 0 free. 67608 cached Mem|`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
let str = "top - 16:04:32 up 69 days, 2 min, 0 users, load average: 0.39, 0.39, 0.41|Tasks: 64 total, 1 running, 63 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie|%Cpu(s): 2.3 us, 11.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 86.3 id, 0.1 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.1 si, 0.0 st|KiB Mem: 511268 total, 171828 used, 339440 free, 71632 buffers|KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 used, 0 free. 67608 cached Mem|";

[match] = str.match(/\|KiB Mem:.+?\|/);

console.log(match);
```

Regex explanation:

> `\|KiB Mem:` match needs to start with this (inclusive)
>
> `.+?` matches any character any number of times until the next pattern below is found
>
> `\|` matches a literal `|`